# Can I use "impression" to mean the act of impressing others?

Tags: word-usage

Can *impression* be used to mean the act, process, or phenomenon (in a very transitory sense) of impressing others, like *entertainment* is used to refer to the activity of entertaining others?

Comment: Here's a tangentially related term, also descring an act of "impressing":  . . https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impressment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually one of the less known definitions of "impress".  As a noun, one of its meanings is "the act of impressing".

Although I have had little need to use it, I expect a sentence might look like:

> The candidate was interesting to watch quarrel, but effort behind his impress was palpable.

Comment: So the answer is you can use *impress* this way, but not *impression*?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Impression is based off the verb impress and is used as a noun form. To impress is to have a strong and favorable affect on someone; To have a strong a strong affect on someone could be done by charm or amusement. To host a party is to entertain as well.

Several synonyms can substitute the meaning of *to entertain* depending on your use for the term.

To describe the act of doing something I would go for a verb form. The process or phenomenon can be described w/a noun, but again it depends on how you decide or wish to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes:

> You only get one chance to make a first impression.